# How to retrieve deep-linked kv pair using jq

Tags: json, key, jq

got to this section of json with jq -r '.update[]' now need to find, operation:restrictions:user:results:username,userKey

```
"update": {
"operation": "update",
"restrictions": {
  "user": {
    "results": [
      {
        "type": "known",
        "username": "xxxx",
        "userKey": "yyyyy",
        "profilePicture": {
          "path": "/download/attachments/49710215/user-avatar",
          "width": 48,
          "height": 48,
          "isDefault": false
        },
        "displayName": "xxxyyyzzz",
        "_links": {
          "self": "aa"
        },
        "_expandable": {
          "status": ""
        }
      },
```

Comment: Did you mean: operation, restrictions:user:results:username,userKey? In either case, it would be a good idea to follow the [mcve] guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input as shown has been tidied a bit to make it valid JSON, running

```
jq -r '
  .update
  | [.operation] + (.restrictions.user.results[] | [.username, .userKey])
  | @csv
'
```

against it would yield:

```
"update","xxxx","yyyyy"
```